# Where do I put my database query tests in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, testing, model

I am coming from a Spring/hibernate background. I have noticed that Rails has no dao and service layers. This really speeds up development, but I don't know where to put my tests sometimes.

Right now, I've been putting my model methods and validation tests in the main model spec. This file is already fairly large.

Where is the 'standard' place to test queries? I can imagine myself making a lot of fixtures/dummy data to make sure my queries are working as expected (probably an even better idea since I am new to rails). These are not really needed for the basic model logic and validation tests.

If you could offer some advice as to where put these tests, the best approach to testing queries using rails (especially ones with multiple joins!), and maybe some basic guidelines of how it might different from doing it with DBunit/spring/hibernate, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "queries".  In Rails, it's better to think about your database as a place to persist objects. ActiveRecord objects to be more precise. The ORM takes care of all the database logic and SQL. Those don't need to be tested unless you are doing something against the convention.

Comment: @Mike Farmer Will ActiveRecord create a complex and effecient sql join between 20 tables if you walk the object graph 20 times before requesting a specific value?

Comment: So long as you setup your associations correctly, I really don't see why not. Coming from a database background, I see your point though. Writing tests to ensure your queries are constructed correctly and are performant is a good idea with the complexity you specified. Modifying some of the finder_sql, counter_sql, delete_sql, and insert_sql for your associations may also be helpful for more complex queries. See (http://j.mp/lOSBkh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to work with hibernate too. The ActiveRecord way is very different from hibernate. You need to set your mind free, for better or for worse. In java and Hibernate you often have the aggregate root and the object graph. Generally, both the object graphs and code base are smaller in ruby somehow too. I don't know your particular case, so I'll tread carefully, but I warn you to try fit ruby, and rails, to your java habits.

You may use custom directories with rspec to organize in a way that makes sense for you and your team.

```
#spec/queries/my_custom_search_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'
describe MyModel do
  it "should do this query and return X" do
     subject.some_defined_scope_search.should == "something"
  end
end
```

and you may have subdirectories, automatically getting picked up by rspec, like `spec/models/account/..`

The spec will automatically be picked up by `rake spec` or `rspec spec`. I just wrote a simple example above, as I don't know your case. Do you define scopes with queries, or define specialized methods?

I strongly recommend abandoning the fixtures (same as the inserts - anti pattern, to me) for something more refactorable, like factories. I like [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). It let's your app evolve in a more agile manner, IMO.

EDIT: 
 adding my spec_helper.rb with settings for enable/disable automatic cleanup

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  require 'database_cleaner'
  config.add_setting :skip_database_clean
  config.skip_database_clean = false
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    MongoMapper.database.collections.each(&:remove)
    DatabaseCleaner.clean unless config.skip_database_clean
  end
```

I add the variable `skip_database_clean` so that I can enable/disable the autocleanup after each spec (each "it").

```
  before :all do
    @an_object = some_expensive_test_buildup
    RSpec.configuration.skip_database_clean = true
  end
  after :all do
    RSpec.configuration.skip_database_clean = false
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using factory girl already. I just find that I need to make 3-4 records, plus their dependencies, to properly test the queries to make sure they are working. So the test setup code ends up being huge since I may have to create a little mini-database to make the tests pass and test out all the query possibilities to ensure the query logic is working.

Comment: how much time does running a spec take? 
You may do the test data build-up in a `before :all` and then have a bunch of query specs on the data. You'll have to disable the global `before :each` if you have automatic cleanup activated (like DatabaseCleaner)

Comment: Actually, moving my tests in a new folder seems to cause rails to not clean things up. Do I need to turn this on somewhere in the environment?

Comment: rails not clean up? Do you mean rspec db-cleanup? You may want to have look at DatabaseCleaner. I'll add some in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses Arel to generate the SQL for your database queries based on relationships you define in Ruby code through the Rails ActiveRecord associations API (assuming you are using ActiveRecord as your ORM, it is the default). You can write your own SQL if you think you can improve upon what is generated automatically (which you can see in the log files).

Usually you will invoke these queries (whether written manually or automatically) through a method call on the model. For example, `@author.books` or `@author.readers`; these could embody a query that has joins.

I'm not sure about hand-written queries, but generated queries are usually built with scopes that once fully constructed are realized when the results are requested. For example, `@author.books.order('price').limit(10)`. You can define your own custom scopes.

I would test the correctness of your custom queries or scopes in the unit test for the model in the case where they are integral to the working of the model. For example, `@author.popular_books` might be a custom scope defined on your model, and you can write a unit test for your `Author` model to ensure that it returns the expected results for some known test data.

Comment: In essence I think you have your tests in the right place. Maybe you could write some test helpers to reduce the length of your code though? Take a look at the Shoulda test framework to get ideas for helpers (you don't need to actually use it, but it does have lots of helpers to do common things like check validations).

Comment: This is how I am currently doing it. Writing these scoped queries starts to become a pain when I need to do multiple joins though, and so I need to create lots of test data in the database to verify that the query is working. This often bloats up the model spec file

Answer (score 0):

If you use normal rails ORM, then you don't create queries, and you don't need to test the data access.

If you do start to write custom SQL queries, then I recommend you use rspec and test the behavior of your objects after you execute the queries.

Comment: How would you use Rails ORM and not create queries...? And I am not asking if I should or shouldn't testing them - I am asking "Where should these tests go?" Do they do in the model spec? In a different spec altogether? Where? I know how to test them - I am asking where.

Comment: If you define your models as rails expects, you don't write queries. You simply: "@account.purchases" and that returns purchases for that account. You can write a spec that purchase should belong_to an account, but that's as far as I'd go.

Comment: That is honestly a horrible way to do it Jesse for very long object graphs. That is not really querying - you are actually PULLING OUT the data from the database. This is awful. If you had to join 20 tables to get the data you want, would you really walk the object graph 20 times? What if there were 100 records in each collection... that would be 100^20 records pulled out of the database! No, the best way to do it is to QUERY - hence the question.

Comment: Hey, your opinion is your own. You'll find as you bring your java ways into rails you will be frustrated.